# Deliberately adding bugs to assess QA processes

Tags: debugging, terminology

How do you know that as many bugs as possiblle have been discovered and solved in a program? 
Couple of years ago I have read a document about debugging (I think it was some sort of HOWTO). Among other things, that document described a technique in which the programming team deliberately adds bugs into the code and passes it to the QA team. The QA process is considered completed when all the deliberately known bugs have been discovered.

Unfortunately, I cannot find this document, or any similar one with description of this trick. Can someone please point me to such a document?

**EDIT**

To make Evgeny happy, let me paraphrase the last sentence of the first paragraph:

"The QA process isn't complete before all the deliberate bugs are found"

Comment: Awesome! Next time QA finds a bug I'll tell them I deliberately added it just to test them... ;)

Comment: hehe, I have been doing this all the time, not only in SW, but in home assignments, tech reports, etc. 
Just kidding :-)

Comment: bgbg is happy that Evgeny is happy

Comment: I am voting to close the question because it's not unique to programming as [defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I came across this in the review queue and was thinking: "Is this an audit?" :-)

Comment: @BendertheGreatest It's not unique to programming but is it "a software tool" (tool as in "way of working", not "a software product")

Comment: Technical questions about QA (such as about debugging or issues implementing testing code) are on topic. This is asking about a specific QA process which is  *not* a unique programming problem or about a tool related to programming. Quality assurance processes span multiple industries, not just software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One name for the technique is 'Fault Injection'.  One of the older books on the subject is ['Software Fault Injection: Inoculating Programs Against Errors'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471183814) by Jeffrey Voas and Gary McGraw.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen such a document, but I'd be wary of saying the QA process is "complete" just because your deliberate bugs have been found. It's a good way of ensuring that your QA team doesn't get too lazy, but you can't really ensure they did *enough* testing.

It's fundamentally impossible to know that all bugs (or "as many bugs as possible") have been discovered. All you can do is follow a thorough, well thought-out testing approach to give yourself a good shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find that there are plenty of bugs for QA to find, without having to inject any deliberate ones !  I'd much rather have my QA team continue to find bugs that I never even imagined could be in the system.

Like Evgeny, I'd be very wary of calling the QA process complete when a set of known bugs has been found.  I prefer to use exit criteria such as:

- Have all features defined for this release been completed ?
- Have all planned test cases been executed ?
- Is the open bug count within the accepted limits (e.g. no critical or high priority bugs, less than 10 low priority bugs, etc.)